# Check if two items have changed

Tags: c#, validation

I am working on a custom validator that needs to fail if either an email address or username haven't changed.  *Essentially if one of the string comparisons are true* then it will pass the validation.  I know I'm overlooking something simple. Here is what I have so far:

```
bool emailChanged = Domain.Validation.ItemsHaveChanged(txtEmailAddress.Text, emailAddress);
bool userNameChanged = Domain.Validation.ItemsHaveChanged(txtUserName.Text, userName);

// make sure at least the email or username has changed.
if (!emailChanged || !userNameChanged)
{
     args.IsValid = false;
     cvAccountChange.ErrorMessage = "There haven't been any changes to the account.";
 }
```

Here is the method `ItemsHaveChanged`

```
public static bool ItemsHaveChanged(string param1, string param2)
{
    return string.Compare(param1.Trim(), param2.Trim()) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [logical AND operator (`&&`):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
if (!emailChanged && !userNameChanged)
{
     args.IsValid = false;
     cvAccountChange.ErrorMessage = "There haven't been any changes to the account.";
}
```

Comment: A better way to see this is by reasoning about when the input is *valid*. The input is valid if the email has changed **or** the user name has changed: `emailChanged || userNameChanged`. Thus, the input is invalid if the opposite is true: `!(emailChanged || userNameChanged)`. Then, [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) states that this is equivalent to `!emailChanged && !userNameChanged`. Hence, the `&&`.

Comment: Mattias, +1 for this nice explanation and mentioning De Morgan

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd avoid the brobdingnagian condition and just do:

```
if (emailChanged || usernameChanged) {
    // everything is fine
    return;
}

// neither changed
args.IsValid = false;
...
```

That is, assuming you can return early from the method. (Besides you can always just extract that code snipped into a separate one.)

Alternately, you can avoid the early return and the complicated expression with:

```
var emailUnchanged = !ItemsHaveChanged(...);
var usernameUnchanged = !ItemsHaveChanged(...);

if (emailUnchanged || usernameUnchanged) {
    // neither changed
    args.IsValid = false;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd tend to agree with you the thought of going the other way is that all the 'actions' would happen in the `else` section which also seems backwards

Comment: @JonHarding In a method of seven lines long I don't think that harms readability at all, or at least no worse than parsing a boolean expression with many negations. I also strongly prefer bailing early in exceptional conditions to avoid [arrow code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html), and "I have nothing to do" can be considered one.

Comment: @JonHarding That said your comment made me think ever so slightly laterally and I've now added another way, which avoids the early return while also making the condition easier to parse by moving the negation into the name of the local variable.